# instantiate object and sub-objects properties via reflection

Tags: c#

i'm searching best way to instantiate and update an object that includes other objects via reflection.

i used GetInstance function but this only creating new object and overriding the object from start.
is there a way to fix the function so it will just return the class of the already updated object instance or creating new instance?
this is the function

```
public static object GetInstance(string strFullyQualifiedName)
    {
        if(strFullyQualifiedName.Split(' ').Length > 1)
        {
            strFullyQualifiedName = strFullyQualifiedName.Split(' ')[0];
        }
        Type type = Type.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
        if (type != null)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            type = asm.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
            if (type != null)
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

this is the object for example

```
public class C
{
    string C1 { get; set; }
    string C2 { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public string B1 { get; set; }
    public string B2 { get; set; }
    public C c { get; set; }
}
public class A
{
    public string A1 { set; get; }
    public string A2 { set; get; }
    public B b { get; set; }
}
```

i built a small project to implement the issue :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a = new A();
    a.b = new B();
    a.b.B1 = "B1";
    
    PropertyInfo propp = a.GetType().GetProperty("b");
    
    propp.SetValue(a, GetInstance("ConsoleApp1.B"), null);
 }
```

one way of trying to solve it was in fixing the function this way

```
.....

    if (type != null)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] pLIST = o.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(PropertyInfo p in pLIST)
        {
            object oo = p.GetValue(o);
            if(oo != null && oo.GetType() == type)
            {
                return oo;
            }
        }
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   }
....

static void Main(string[] args)
{
......
            propp.SetValue(a, GetInstance("ConsoleApp1.B",a), null);
......
}
```

Comment: You need to explain much, much better what you're trying to do, cause I'm reading what you wrote and all I can think of is "why reflection? Just initialize your object properties in-place." like `public C c { get; } = new();`

Comment: Hi @Blindy, i want to build dynamic mechanism that is not coupled to anything , the only object that will be available will be the root object and besides the rest need to be updated by inner data that will be updated via the reflection because the object will be change but data will be very repetitive

Comment: You can't get an instance of an object without having a pointer to it. You will need to keep track of the instance you create when you create an instance.

Comment: can you give an example(please see what i sent in the last part of the question), i need to send the object together with the property in order to compare, does it make sense? in the end of the day if my object is nested i need to loop the object till i reach to the object and if i see its already instantiate it will be returned otherwise it will return activator of type

Comment: I still don't see why you don't initialize your properties in place and then navigate your hierarchy like a normal human being `a.b`.

Answer (score 0):

this function worked for me for a nested object

```
public static object GetInstance(string strFullyQualifiedName)
    {
        if(strFullyQualifiedName.Split(' ').Length > 1)
        {
            strFullyQualifiedName = strFullyQualifiedName.Split(' ')[0];
        }
        Type type = Type.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
if (type != null)
    {
        ***PropertyInfo[] pLIST = o.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(PropertyInfo p in pLIST)
        {
            object oo = p.GetValue(o,null);
            if(oo != null && oo.GetType() == type)
            {
                return oo;
            }
        }***
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
   }
        foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            type = asm.GetType(strFullyQualifiedName);
            if (type != null)
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        return null;
    }
```